# how to get object from a class which annotated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class lets say Test as below

```
@Component
public class Test implements TestInterface

@Autowired 
private interface1 i1;
```

There is a class C1

```
@Component 
public class C1 implements interface1
```

and I am calling this class as below

```
@Bean
public void xyx(){

new Test();
```

when I debug then I am getting i1 as null.

Please advise what I am doing wrong

Note:. I have to use class Test inside xyx() because its a pseudo code and there lots of codes inside xyx()

Comment: These should be capitalized: `@Component` and `@Autowired`; along with `Interface1`. Take a look at Java code style conventions.

Comment: its just a pseudo code

Comment: But you tagged it for Spring, and those are actual annotations.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl changes does as per your suggestions,thanks

Comment: Are you manually creating new instances of `Test` using `new Test()`, not using dependency injection?

Comment: @AlexCheng yes because I am following the others code

Comment: What does your project structur look like? Do you have a multiple modules? Because Spring scans all classes on the same lvl and nested, so you have to tell Spring to scan certain packages for multi module project. (Just anonther thought I had)

Answer (score 0):

You can Inject the Interface as parameter into your Bean method and then use the constructor of `Test` to set the field. With that you also get the advantage to set `i1` final :D

```java
@Bean
public Test xyx(YourInterface interface){
    Test test = new Test(interface);
    // do stuff 
    return Test
}
```

Comment: Please explain in pseudo code

Comment: thanks, let me try

Comment: it didnt work, I am getting compile time error as no beans of interface found

Comment: Are you sure that you have a subclass with Component annotation?

Comment: So I rebuild this little scenario and I'm able to Autowire the Test Bean and Interface. Could you give us some more information about your project

Comment: I cannot provide here as it is public domain, do you have gmail?